# How to query/interpret parameter which has string value such as "List(1,30)"?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table :

| id | condition_value | parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | List(1,30) | 40 |
| 2 | 44 | 50 |

I need my query to extract parameter based on `condition_value`:

```
SELECT parameter WHERE condition_value=25
```

My query does not return anything. What I need to be returned is 40 (because 25 is in [1,2,3...,30].

Comment: If you want to query "ranges", wouldn't the SQL `Between` keyword together two separate Int columns like "condition_Lo" and "condition_Hi" work better than the overloaded the "condition_value" column?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I decided to go with this approach because it simplifies the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like ***(see better below)***:-

```
SELECT 
    parameter
FROM simple
WHERE 25 BETWEEN
    CASE 
        WHEN instr(condition_value,'List(')
        THEN CAST(substr(condition_value,length('List(')+1,(instr(condition_value,',')-length('List('))-1) AS INTEGER)
        ELSE CAST(condition_value AS INTEGER) 
    END
AND
    CASE 
        WHEN instr(condition_value,'List(')
        THEN CAST(substr(condition_value,instr(condition_value,',')+ 1,instr(condition_value,')')-instr(condition_value,',')-1) AS INTEGER)
        ELSE CAST(condition_value AS INTEGER)
    END
;
```

However, a better, more flexible and simpler, solution would be to introduce another column so that a range of values can be specified.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS better (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cvlow, cvhigh, parameter);
```

The following demonstrates both:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS simple;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simple (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, condition_value TEXT, parameter INTEGER);
INSERT INTO simple (condition_value,parameter) VALUES 
    ('List(1,30)',40),
    ('List(25,25)',41),
    ('List(-100,25)',42),
    ('List(-1,-25)',43),
    ('List(1,2500000)',44),
    (44,50)
;
SELECT 
    parameter
FROM simple
WHERE 25 BETWEEN
    CASE 
        WHEN instr(condition_value,'List(')
        THEN CAST(substr(condition_value,length('List(')+1,(instr(condition_value,',')-length('List('))-1) AS INTEGER)
        ELSE CAST(condition_value AS INTEGER) 
    END
AND
    CASE 
        WHEN instr(condition_value,'List(')
        THEN CAST(substr(condition_value,instr(condition_value,',')+ 1,instr(condition_value,')')-instr(condition_value,',')-1) AS INTEGER)
        ELSE CAST(condition_value AS INTEGER)
    END
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS simple;

/* BETTER simpler and with greater flexibility*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS better (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cvlow, cvhigh, parameter);
INSERT INTO better (cvlow,cvhigh,parameter) VALUES 
    (1,30,40),
    (25,25,41),
    (-100,25,42),
    (-1,-25,43),
    (1,2500000,44),
    (44,44,50) /* the equivalent of the single value */
;
SELECT parameter FROM better WHERE 25 BETWEEN cvlow AND cvhigh;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS better;
```

The results being the same:-

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer. I will test it in following days.